See me once, See me twice #17

See me once, naturally, my integrity is undenied
See me twice, the outcome I can yet decide

First Hint:

 See me once, some say that I am shady
 See me twice, the chances are quite risky

If you are not familiar with my See me once riddles, I recommend you first have a look at the latest riddles in this series and their solutions:
#12, #13, #14, #15, #16

I think the answer is

 50

See me once, naturally, my integrity is undenied

 50 is a natural number, that also makes it a whole (which is one of the meanings of integrity) number and an integer (root of word integrity)

See me twice, the outcome I can yet decide

 50-50 means the outcome can go either way

Hint explanations:

 See me once, some say that I am shady
 Reference to 50 shades of grey - the book / film series


 See me twice, the chances are quite risky
 A 50-50 chance is quite risky, as the chance of losing is 50%


You are correct! But the explanation for the first line still needs some work ;)

Thanks @kscherrer! rot13(vf vg n ersrerapr gb gur crepragntr zrnavat haovnfrq?)

No thats not it either. It's hard to give a hint without giving it away. rot13(vg unf gb qb jvgu zngu onfvpf)

Thank you, updated answer - I think my explanation works now.

yep that's it. Well done!
